# Using C function in another function

Tags: c

I know that this has been answered, but I still can't get it to work.

first.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "second.h"

int main(void){
  printf("%d\n", addone(5));
  return 0;
}
```

second.c

```
int addone(int a){
  return ++a;
}
```

second.h

```
int addone(int a);
```

When I run `gcc -o executable first.c -Wall` then it shows me `undefined reference to addone`

Comment: `gcc -o executable first.c second.c -Wall`

Comment: Alternative: `gcc -c -o first.o first.c -Wall; gcc -c -o second.o second.c -Wall; gcc -o executable first.o second.o;`.

Comment: `gcc -o second.o second.c -Wall` then `gcc -o executable first.c second.o -Wall`

Comment: "I know that this has been answered" - where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "second.h"
```

include those headers in second.c file too and then write Makefile and compile it with make.

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -g -O -Wall
OBJ = first.o second.o

# An explicit rule is required to link.
# Compilation is handled automatically.
first: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o first $(OBJ)

# Declare that both object files depend on the header file.
first.o second.o: second.h

# Conventionally 'make clean' removes what 'make' creates.
# Not strictly required.    
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f first $(OBJ)
```

You can't just copy and paste the above; you must also change both indented lines (the ones with shell commands on them) so that the indentation is a single hard <kbd>TAB</kbd> character.  If you don't do this you will get a cryptic error message:

> Makefile:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.

first.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "second.h"

int main(void){
  printf("%d\n", addone(5));
  return 0;
}
```

second.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "second.h"

int addone(int a){
  return ++a;
}
```

second.h

```
#include <stdio.h>

int addone(int a);
```